# Studies that identify the best frequencies for transmitting interstellar messages?

Tags: communication, seti, meti

We are searching for extraterrestrial communications from other solar systems, and some consider sending them as well. Are there studies attempting to identify which wavelengths are best suited for such transmissions and/or most likely to be used?

These might include:

- Radio?
- Thermal Infrared?
- Near Infrared?
- Visible light?
- X rays?

Comment: possibly helpful/related: [Optical Detection of Lasers with Near-term Technology at Interstellar Distances](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-4357/aae380/pdf) and also [Which colors would extraterrestrial civilizations use to transmit signals?: The “magic wavelengths” for optical SETI](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1384107616301993) and also [What (actually) does “peculiar periodic spectral modulations” refer to in this preprint?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/18856/7982)

Comment: I am pretty sure I have read it somewhere, perhaps in a one of the many reports by SETI.org, but I have to find it again. You also have the [NASA technosignatures workshop report](https://www.hou.usra.edu/meetings/technosignatures2018/agenda/Technosignature-Report.pdf). Although it is focused on unintentional signals, there is a common logic with intentional communication in that you would better avoid frequencies/characteristics shared with lots of natural sources. As always, the starting working assumption is that "they" make the same reasoning.