# How could METI laser pulses be "brighter than the Sun"?

Tags: laser, meti

This Astronomy online course page [The Search for Extraterrestrial Intelligence](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/astronomy/chapter/the-search-for-extraterrestrial-intelligence/) contains the following, about half-way down:

> **However, in recent years, human engineers have learned how to make flashes of light brighter than the Sun.** The trick is to “turn on” the light for a very brief time, so that the costs are manageable. But ultra-bright, ultra-short laser pulses (operating for periods of a billionth of a second) can pack a lot of energy and can be coded to carry a message. We also have the technology to detect such short pulses—not with human senses, but with special detectors that can be “tuned” to hunt automatically for such short bursts of light from nearby stars.

While I'd [mentioned](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48722/are-we-sending-data-for-extraterrestrial-seti?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment157552_48728) that pulsed lasers can be pretty powerful instantaneously, "brighter than the Sun" didn't occur to me.

Is this factually true? As seen from space, say 100 AU or farther, during a brief pulse, would one of these lasers really be brighter than the Sun? Are some assumptions made for this to be true?

Comment: Lasers can put their output into a very narrow range of wavelengths, and it's certainly feasible to outshine the sun within a sufficiently narrow range. But you'd need to know exactly what wavelengths to look at, and it doesn't sound like this is what they're talking about. This sounds like ultrafast pulses that are very briefly brighter than the the full spectrum output of the sun, which would be detectable without requiring the recipient to know exactly what wavelengths to look at.

Comment: Note that another thing lasers can do is produce diffraction-limited beams given good optics...they're still subject to inverse square falloff, but very large telescopes can direct much more of the laser power to the target.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff these are great points! With $\Delta f \Delta t \approx 0.44$, the bandwidth of fs pulses will be as broad as most of the Sun's spectrum

Comment: "at 100 AU" the sun's pretty dim :-) . You just need to project a very-well-collimated beam, preferable soliton-shaped, to prevent spreading. (not saying this is possible, just a thought)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I think solitons can only occur in a nonlinear medium where the (usually electric) field strength is high, neither of which really apply here.

Comment: @uhoh (solitons) I think you're correct, because they depend on dispersion effects

Comment: @CarlWitthoft There has to be a *non-linear* response to field strength as well. No matter what the dispersion looks like, I don't think a linear medium can support solitons, but I'm not 100% sure if that's always true in all cases.